# Iteratee is not a member of package play.api.libs

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

While upgrading from `play 2.4 -> 2.5` I hit an issue where

`Symbol 'type <none>.iteratee.Iteratee' is missing from the classpath`

I checked the migration guide and included the dependency `"com.typesafe.play" % "play-iteratees_2.11" % 2.5.18` into sbt. From the new play-iteratees [repo](https://github.com/playframework/play-iteratees/blob/master/iteratees/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/iteratee/Iteratee.scala), I was under the impression that `package play.api.libs.iteratee` is where I'd find what to import. But it doesnt seem to work?

Error log:

```
[error] /Users/arnogau/Documents/alice/common/src/main/scala/common/util/Autodesk.scala:23: object iteratee is not a member of package play.api.libs
[error] import play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee
[error]                      ^
[error] /Users/arnogau/Documents/alice/common/src/main/scala/common/util/Autodesk.scala:158: Symbol 'type <none>.iteratee.Iteratee' is missing from the classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by 'method play.api.libs.ws.WSRequest.get'.
[error] Make sure that type Iteratee is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'WSRequest.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of <none>.iteratee.
[error]     val req = client.url(MANIFEST_URL(urn)).withToken(token).get()
[error]                                                       ^
[error] two errors found
```

Comment: The dependency must be added explicitly in the build